# strech font in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to strech text in CSS.

For me, `font-strech` property doesn't work.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

And be sure to use `streTch` instead of `strech`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_font-stretch.cfm and see if the test at the bottom of the page works

Comment: Are stretched versions of the font in question available to your browser? Does IE 7 even support this property?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 .stretch { -webkit-transform: scaleX(2);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(2); }
```